# Vue.js or Nuxt.js centralized app configuration

Tags: vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

How can I load my static data in a single location within a nuxt/vue app?

Ideally I would have a JSON file holding all this data which would get loaded into vuex and would be accessible anywhere...

I've been suggested 2 options, but I don't find them clean...

- When using the webpack template (not webpack-simple), you can use environment variables for that: http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html.
- Alternatively, you can always just create some file - constants.js  - anywhere in your project folder, which you use to store your static data (e.g. `export const API_URL = 'https:/my-api.com'` ).

Import the data from that file anywhere you need it (e.g. `import { API_URL } from 'path/to/constants'` ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found an elegant solution using vue prototype

Hence with Nuxt.js

1) Create a plugin at `~/plugins/globals.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import globals from '~/globals.json'
import _get from 'lodash/get'

Vue.prototype.$g = (key) => {
  let val = _get(globals, key, '')
  if (!val) console.warn(key, ' is empty in $g')
  return val || key
}
```

2) Create your json file at `~/global.json`

```
{
  "website_url": "https://www.company.com",
  "social": {
    "facebook": {
      "url": "https://www.facebook.com/company"
    },
    "twitter": {
      "url": "https://www.twitter.com/company"
    }
  }
}
```

3) Use these in every `.vue` file

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>URL: {{ $g('website_url') }}</p>
    <p>Facebook: {{ fburl }}</p>
    <p><a :href="$g('social.twitter.url')">twitter</a></p>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      fburl: this.$g('social.facebook.url')
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one easiest way to set configs (json) file and and use in any component.

Steps -

1. Create `setting.json` file in root directory.
2. in middleware, create a file settings.js (or keep any name) and paste this code

```
    import settings from '../settings.json'
    export default function ({ store, route, redirect, req}) {
        process.env = settings
    }
```

3 in nuxt.config.js - add settings in

```
     router: {
            middleware: ['users', 'settings']
      },
```

uses -
In any component or page -

```
data(){
      return {
            settings: process.env
      }
},
```

**Now you can use settings anywhere in component.**

Comment: Thanks for your contribution ! Now using process.env to pass this kind of information sounds like a very bad idea to me. Also I don't really see how this solution is more elegant than mine ?

Comment: your answer is also good. However, In my project i have multiple settings based on environment so i am keeping `settings/dev.json` and `settings/prod.json` and loading this file on `ENV` which is set at very first in `nuxt-config.js`